# Vim Home Row Navigation Not Scrolling But Directional Arrows Do

Tags: macos, vim, text-editor

When the arrow keys are used in Vim, the cursor scrolls at my current rate (**`defaults write NSGlobalDomain KeyRepeat -int 0`** (very fast)), but when using **`'h', 'j', 'k'`** or **`'l'`**, scrolling doesn't occur. Any suggestions?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7406814/in-vim-how-do-you-scroll-a-buffer-so-the-cursor-location-is-centered-in-the-scr/7406927

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify, your arrow keys are simply moving the cursor (which may induce scrolling) at an extremely fast rate. This is done by your system (by your configuration) not by Vim.

I ran into this issue myself, when I wanted an easier way to scroll code without having to constantly press jk. Here's a couple of solutions I found:

1. Using <C-f> and <C-b>, which scroll the screen up one page or down one page. More similiar commands can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458689/how-to-move-screen-without-moving-cursor-in-vim)
2. Try out [vim easy motion](https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-easymotion), which makes motion as a whole in vim easier
3. Finally, try typing in the command:

   ```
   defaults write NSGlobalDomain ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
   ```

   By default, mac allows a fancy feature when pressing a key, options are induced (such as accents and the like). It might be possible that vim is being tricked by that feature.

Answer (score 0):

First, `hjkl` don't scroll, they move the cursor which *may* provoke scrolling. If you want to scroll, use actual scroll commands:

```
" scroll by one line
<C-e>
<C-y>

" scroll by half screen
<C-u>
<C-d>

" scroll by full screen
<C-b>
<C-f>
```

See `:help scrolling`.

Second, did you try other values? Maybe there's a threshold beyond which Vim stops responding?