# VIM: Avoid a search result is shown at the first or last line of the screen?

Tags: vim, vi, neovim

If I search forward or backwards (via `/` and `?`) in VIM it will show results at the last line of the screen (when searched forward) or first line of the screen (when searched backwards).

The problem is that in this case I can't see the lines before or after the search result without moving the cursor up/down.

**How can I force VIM to scroll the search result to the middle of the screen or alternatively scroll it in such way that always X lines before and after the search result are visible in the terminal screen?**

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7406927/7976758 `set scrolloff=5` Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+scroll+search+result+middle

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In vim, how do you scroll a buffer so the cursor location is centered in the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7406814/in-vim-how-do-you-scroll-a-buffer-so-the-cursor-location-is-centered-in-the-scr)

Comment: `:help 'scrolloff'` is mentioned in chapter 3 and 5 of the user manual. That's, like something you learn on day two or something.

Answer (score 0):

1. `set scrolloff=10` will force vim to keep 10 min lines above and below the cursorline
2. You can force vim to keep cursor in the middle of the screen when navigating to the next & prev search results by remapping n and N keys

```
nnoremap n nzz
nnoremap N Nzz
```

> `zz` is a keymap to move the cursor line to middle of the screen